# WordPress using images in sage template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use a background image in one of my Sage template files.

However when I try this the image is not being displayed.

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);">
```

The `banner.jpg` file is located in `theme-name/assets/images/banner.jpg`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share path where this code file is?

Comment: @AnkurBhadania It's in the header.php template file of the Sage project so `theme-name/templates/header.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with below code. You need to add  `assets` before image folder because as per your image path you mention images folder is sub folder of assets

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/banner.jpg');">
```

> Used `get_template_directory_uri()`. It Retrieve theme directory URI.

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/banner.jpg');">
```

> Used `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` if you used child theme .It return URI for the current theme/child theme

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/banner.jpg');">
```

Comment: Yes there is an images folder I just forgot it, it's a typo

Comment: It's in local development

Comment: @Chris this answer was slowed your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers use some of WordPress' built-in functions for resolving a path to the current theme. However, in Sage (using Blade templates) this is handled with the `@asset` directive:

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url("@asset('images/example.jpg')");">
```

[Documentation](https://roots.io/sage/docs/theme-development-and-building/#images-in-template-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/banner.jpg);">
```

or this:

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/banner.jpg');">
```

or maybe you just forgot "assets":

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url('../assets/images/banner.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use wordpress template directory path

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/images/banner.jpg);">
```

Comment: User this <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> instead of  <?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your header.php:

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url(wp-content/themes/theme-name/dist/images/about-us-top-side.png);">
```

or

```
<section class="banner" style="background-image: url(wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/images/about-us-top-side.png);">
```

The first one will have the optimized image if you are using the Sage theme properly.